# Multiple Serial Numbers?

Tags: serial-number

[image]I need help identifying this mystery bike i bought a while back, there’s specialized stickers on it but it was clearly painted and the stickers put on, has a fox f100 rl don’t know if it came with it or not, shimano xt m760 if that helps. [image] i have changed the sram 3x crankset and switched to mechanical brakes until i get the xt’s fixed
serial says “M8GK” “29678” “8ST1” Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  There is no standard for serial numbers, so they are of very limited use in making an identification.  What might help more is adding more photos of the bike.

Comment: A clear well-lit side-on photo of the frame would be more useful to identify it: details like the shape of the dropout castings, replaceable gear hanger, tube profiles and cable routing are informative.

Comment: I see you've posted a similar ID question.  Shall we merge them together ?

Answer (score 1):

According [to Specialized](https://www.specialized.com/us/en/faq#:%7E:text=For%20bikes%2C%20the%20serial%20number%20is%20located%20on,with%20the%20prefix%20%E2%80%9CWSBC%2C%E2%80%9D%20%E2%80%9CWUD%2C%E2%80%9D%20%E2%80%9CSTT%2C%E2%80%9D%20or%20%E2%80%9CSTE.%E2%80%9D):

> For bikes, the serial number is located on a sticker on the underside of your toptube and/or downtube as well as on the underside of your bike, underneath the bottom bracket. Specialized serial numbers typically start with the prefix “WSBC,” “WUD,” “STT,” or “STE.”

The quote says "typically" which means there are exceptions.
Even if your serial number started with those prefixes it's possible that some other frame maker used WSBC, WUD, STT or STE at the beginning of their serial numbers.
There is no governing body for serial numbers.

All I can say for sure is that your serial numbers are not typical for a Specialized bike.